# Sqlite - No Such Column Error while deleting table from sqlite_sequence

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to clear a table that has autoincrement key.

I am trying to do the following, by i get an exception.

```
protected void clearSqliteSequenceTable(String table) {
        String query = "delete from sqlite_sequence where name = business";
        mDb.execSQL(query);
    }
```

the table name is business. I get the following no such column business exception.

```
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204): Process: com.xx.xxx, PID: 20204
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.xxx/com.xx.xxx.SplashActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: business (code 1): , while compiling: delete from sqlite_sequence where name = business
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: business (code 1): , while compiling: delete from sqlite_sequence where name = business
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1672)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.xx.xxx.database.BaseDbAdapter.clearSqliteSequenceTable(BaseDbAdapter.java:65)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.xx.xxx.database.adapters.BusinessDbAdapter.clearSqliteSequenceTable(BusinessDbAdapter.java:149)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.xx.xxx.SplashActivity.insertDummyData(SplashActivity.java:79)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at com.xx.xxx.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:51)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
09-11 15:53:33.709: E/AndroidRuntime(20204):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "where" statement of

```
 name = business
```

tries to delete from the table `sqlite_sequence` where the `name` column equals a hypothetical`business` column. If you are trying to delete from `sqlite_sequence` where the name column contains the *value* "business", try

```
String query = "DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'business'";
```

Comment: Where do i end double quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your query

from

```
String query = "delete from sqlite_sequence where name = business";
```

to

```
String query = "delete from sqlite_sequence where name = \'business\' ";
```

I have tried its working fine :-)

Comment: Can you modify your answer by including the quotes? I mean String query = ""; i am confused on how to use quotes for business

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void clearSqliteSequenceTable(String table) {
    String query = "delete from " + table;
    mDb.execSQL(query);
}
```